# How to force nested dynamic component HTML content in standard layout with CSS grid?

Tags: css, angular, css-grid

I have a pretty standard layout of [menu column] + [content], and shoehorning the [content] part in the predefined layout proved to be difficult.

Working with Angular, so very few things are clear-cut HTML, a lot of it is made up of components with all the baggage that has.

The base content template area consists of a list and an editor with a save/cancel component. User clicks list row, editor gets populated.

```
-----------------------------------
|               |                 |
| list items    | editor          |
|               |                 |
|               |                 |
|               |   |-------------|
|               |   |cancel | save|
-----------------------------------
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="list">
        <app-list>
    </div>
    <div class="editor">
        <app-editor>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button>Cancel</button>
            <button>Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when the editor section has to consist of 2 columns in itself, because the data has a preview (image) associated with it

```
-----------------------------------
|           |       |             |
| list items|     editor          |
|           |preview|   form      |
|           |       |             |
|           |       |-------------|
|           |       |cancel | save|
-----------------------------------
```

The content needs to turn into a 3-column, but the layout tmeplate is still just a 2 column. The issue is that when the content is injected, it needs to take up the whole height of the enclosing grid. Now the button section prevents this, because it tries to stack them on top of each other so it looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------
|           |       |             |
| list items|     editor          |
|           |preview|   form      |
|           |       |             |
|           |-------|-------------|
|           |       |cancel | save|
-----------------------------------
```

I don't know how the desired layout could be achieved, because the layout is injected with all sorts of Angular elements, so I can't really make a clean css, and I don't know how to style the content of the editor to fit into an outer css (if that makes sense).

Comment: @Paulie_D I resent your assumption that I _I did not attempt solving this_, or that _I didn't make an attempt_

Comment: If you don't **demonstrate** your research, we have to assume there was none. You don't provide any example HTML or CSS. All you did was a **problem-dump** and that's not what we solve here.

Comment: @romeozor could you setup a StackBlitz with the base HTML elements and I could take a shot at layout for you. We can work through this together. SO is brutal BTW, it's clear that you did explain the layout the best of your ability, only it's too difficult to fix without StackBlitz.